# Is that possible to use the passing data form another page in Statefulwidget without using "widget."

Tags: flutter, class, dart, statefulwidget

Hi guy I kind of new to this tool and I'd like some of your help. Let's me explain what tying to do, I'm have a `Nav()` Statefulwidget that passing `bool` form a another page to check that now the person that using the app is "User" or "Guest" and in `Nav()` I use **BottomNavigationBarItem** widget. Now the issue is **BottomNavigationBarItem** need to create the list outside the `BuildContext` and in the list is contain the page that need to navigate. I have one page that name `Profile()` that also need to passing the `bool` to check the user status too and I'd like to use the `bool user` that already passed to pass the data to `Profile()` page but it look like I can't call the `user` outside `BuildContext`. I even use `widget.user` but it still got an error said 
"*The instance member 'widget' can't be accessed in an initializer.
Try replacing the reference to the instance member with a different expression*"
Is that anyway out that I can call the `user` outside the `BuildContext`?
So if there is anyone who can help me I will be very thankful.

Here is the code:

```
class Nav extends StatefulWidget {
  const Nav({Key? key, required this.user}) : super(key: key);

  final bool user;

  @override
  _NavState createState() => _NavState();
}

class _NavState extends State<Nav> {
  int _selectedIndex = 0;
  final bool _user = widget.user;
  final List<Widget> _widgetOptions = <Widget>[
    Home(),
    News(),
    Timeline(),
    Manual(),
    Profile(user: _user),
  ];

  void _onItemTap(int index) {
    setState(() {
      _selectedIndex = index;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: IndexedStack(
          index: _selectedIndex,
          children: _widgetOptions,
        ),
      ),
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
        type: BottomNavigationBarType.fixed,
        backgroundColor: const Color(0xFF20348F),
        selectedItemColor: Colors.amber,
        unselectedItemColor: Colors.white54,
        items: [
          bottomNav(const Icon(Icons.home), 'Home'),
          bottomNav(const Icon(Icons.line_style_outlined), 'News'),
          bottomNav(const Icon(Icons.location_pin), 'Timeline'),
          bottomNav(const Icon(Icons.my_library_books_outlined), 'Manual'),
          bottomNav(const Icon(Icons.person), 'Profile'),
        ],
        currentIndex: _selectedIndex,
        onTap: _onItemTap,
        selectedFontSize: 15.0,
      ),
    );
  }
}

BottomNavigationBarItem bottomNav(Icon Icon, String Txt) {
  return BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Icon, label: Txt);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using null-safety version, you can initialize them like that.

```
class _NavState extends State<Nav> {
  int _selectedIndex = 0;
  late bool _user;
  late List<Widget> _widgetOptions;

  @override
  void initState() {
    _user = widget.user;
    _widgetOptions = <Widget>[
      Home(),
      News(),
      Timeline(),
      Manual(),
      Profile(user: _user),
    ];
    super.initState();
  }
```

Also I strongly suggest you to use enum instead of bool for specifying user type.

Comment: Thank you kind sir!! Now my app can run smoothly. Although do you have any advice for using an 'enum'? Like I said I kind of new to this stuff.

Comment: You can use an enum like this:

`enum UserType { user, guest }`
Then you can check it like 
`if (userType == user) {}`
See the following tutorial: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/data-enumeration-in-dart/